# select multiple platform using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Right now i could select only one platform but how can i select multiple platform. I have tried using array of platform but it did not work. That way even one platform does not gets selected when clicked.

Here is what i have done

```
const socialPlatforms = [
  { name: 'facebook', fontName: 'facebook-square', icon: 'facebook-icon' },
  { name: 'twitter', fontName: 'twitter-square', icon: 'twitter-icon' },
  { name: 'instagram', fontName: 'instagram', icon: 'instagram-icon' },
];

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => (
  {
    handleSubscription: (subscription) => dispatch(subscriptionHandled(subscription)),
    selectPlatform: (platform) => dispatch(addPlatform(platform)),
  }
);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    settings: state.settings,
  };
}

class Settings extends React.PureComponent {

  addPlatform = (...platform) => {
    this.props.selectPlatform(platform);
  }

  render() {
    const { settings } = this.props;
    const socialPlatform = socialPlatforms.map((platform, index) =>
      <FontAwesome
        name={platform.fontName}
        key={index}
        className={`icon-pointer font-awesome-icons ${settings.platform === platform.name ? platform.icon : ''}`}
        size="5x"
        onClick={() => { this.addPlatform(platform.name); }}
      />
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Settings Page</h1>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
              {socialPlatform}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Settings);



const initialState = {
  platform: [],
};

export default(state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PLATFORM:
      return { ...state, platform: action.platform };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use array, you need to need to change reducer logic in such way:

```js
const initialState = {
    platforms: [],
};

export default(state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_PLATFORM:
            const index = state.platforms.indexOf(action.platform);
            if (index === -1) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    platforms: [...state.platforms, action.platform]
                };
            } else {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    platforms: state.platforms.filter(
                        localIndex => localIndex !== index
                    )
                };
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Then your className calculation will be like this:

```
className={`icon-pointer font-awesome-icons ${settings.platforms.indexOf(platform.name) === -1 ? '' : platform.icon}`}
```

Comment: Yes it worked for me. Thanks for the solution. Why did you use filter function?

Comment: it does not toggle this way. I mean if i select the selected item it should be unchecked. But it is not happening

Comment: `filter` method allows to produce new array without some items. Could you debug `index` value in console?

Comment: if i click on facebook icon, the index will be -1 and if i again click the same facebook icon, the index will be now 0 only. Similarly If i click twitter icon, i get index -1 at first but again clicking on that twitter icon gives index value of 1 everytime.